# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' in Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm new to django and Google App Engine, and I'm having trouble with using the datastore. Every time I make a query, such as

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Listing ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10")
```

I receive the error:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
```

This error seems to be generated in context_processors.py within the django core. Now, the advice I've found on the Internet said to comment out user-related INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but this does not seem to help. My code looks like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
#    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
#    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
#    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
#    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
#    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
)
```

My Listing object is defined as the following (it had a author property earlier, but this is now commented out and the object was redefined with a new name):

```
class Listing(db.Model):
    #author = db.UserProperty()
    address = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    coords = db.GeoPtProperty()
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error, and how to fix it? Is it perhaps a case of having to reset the settings somehow?

Comment: Please include the exception stacktrace.

Comment: If you removed all the auth apps, you'll also need to comment out the auth context processor that's set in `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The solution suggested by sdolan seems to be to add the following to the settings.py of the app:

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n")

This effectively **removes** the third default processor, django.core.context_processors.auth (which shouldn't be there because for AppEngine we don't want Django's auth component).

Thank you, sdolan, for the solution! hopefully someone else can use it, too. :)

**@Nick**, I think it's worth putting this golden piece about CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in the tutorial (http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html)

**(Original followup to the question)**

Have the same problem, looking for solution.... All works fine when settings.py contains

DEBUG = True

but this error pops up (and kills my motivation to proceed with learning) when I switch to

DEBUG = False

@Nick Johnson, here's the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3211, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3154, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 527, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2404, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2314, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2212, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    script_module.main()
  File "C:\Dev\appengine\djangotest\main.py", line 37, in main
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 97, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 115, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 103, in get_response
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\views\defaults.py", line 79, in page_not_found
    return http.HttpResponseNotFound(t.render(RequestContext(request, {'request_path': request.path})))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\template\context.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.update(processor(request))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django\django\core\context_processors.py", line 18, in auth
    'user': request.user,
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: Thanks -- I never answered with the stack trace, since I gave up on GAE (and redid all the relevant code) before anyone added a comment.